# Struggling with adding spring security for angular js application

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to configure login view from angular js in spring project. Below is the spring security xml setting that I have..

```
<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="theiaFormAuthenticationFilter"/>
      <custom-filter ref="theiaRestDigestFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
      <logout logout-success-url="/#/login" />
      <session-management invalid-session-url="/#/login" />
      <access-denied-handler error-page="/loginFailed"/>
</http>
```

It gives me `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` whenever I try to go to any page even `localhost/#/login`. Please help. Been working on this since past two days and going no where.

Thank you.

Update:

Actually now i changed the code to use the Spring security config class. Its able to give a default login page that comes with spring security. But I am not able to add the angularjs route for login. Below is the code for security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").roles("ADMIN");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("root123").roles("ADMIN","DBA");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.info("Configuring theia security settings.");
    http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/libs/**").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/#/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
}
```

It doesnt seem to recognize /#/login. In this application we dont have a index page. It directly has to go to login page. Anyway to add angular route in the config file?  Am i missing something?

I am following this tutorial now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zu8COg80q4

Comment: what is the definition of 'theiaFormAuthenticationFilter' and 'loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint' ?

Comment: which url do you invoke, and to which url redirect the redirects?  (try to exclude the login urls form the one that are protected, also consider the resources (js, css, images...))

Comment: Actually now i changed the code to use the Spring security config class. Its able to give a default login page that comes with spring security. But I am not able to add the angularjs route for login. Below is the code for security:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this tutorial.. The best tutorial that you will have for this purpose. It goes step by step from the simple app to the most complicated with oauth2 and splitted server. Very recommended:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

EDIT:
Becuase you are using angularjs you cannot do what you are doing. Spring security will just save on assets and not listen to url.
This is Single page application so all the control on the webflow should be on client.

You should use something like that:

```
http
        .httpBasic()
      .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

So server you don't give you resource when client tries to get it without permission. In the client you will need to do the routing logic.

Actually something like that:

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ]) // ... omitted code
.controller('navigation',

  function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {

  var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

    var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
        + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
    } : {};

    $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).success(function(data) {
      if (data.name) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
      } else {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      }
      callback && callback();
    }).error(function() {
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      callback && callback();
    });

  }

  authenticate();
  $scope.credentials = {};
  $scope.login = function() {
      authenticate($scope.credentials, function() {
        if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
          $location.path("/");
          $scope.error = false;
        } else {
          $location.path("/login");
          $scope.error = true;
        }
      });
  };
});
```

In the server when you will try to send get /user the server will return the session user if the user session is alive. So in the server you need also:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class UiApplication {

  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: I have seen this tutorial. But can u check my update once. The angular js route doesnt seem to be recognozied ! It goes to 404 page whenever i try to go to localhost/#/login

Comment: See my edit. I took the important things.. Understand simple thing.. Because angularjs is not really diffrent pages but one page you cannot say spring to redirect to another pages. All the logic routing logic should be on client side. You can only protect resource on the server for authenticated users that will try to reach restricted area

Comment: Thanks Aviad. I got it working by just changing the authentication in AngularJS UI side.